# Converting RestSharp Reqest AddParameter to JavaScript data for POST requests

Tags: javascript, c#, post, restsharp, rest-client

Would anyone know what is the equivalent of RestSharp:

```
request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

in Javascript? That is the only part I am missing.

Here is working code in C#:

```
        public static void UploadFile(string bearer)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("...");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

        var imageLenngth = new FileInfo(@"...").Length;

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", imageLenngth.ToString());

        byte[] body = File.ReadAllBytes(@"...");

        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

And not fully working code in Ajax JavaScript (it uploads to cloud server, but uploads image incorrectly. Inserts corrupted image with way too many more bytes that it should):

```js
    function uploadingImage(binaryImage) {
        
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "...",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
                "Authorization": "Bearer ...",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
            },
            "data": binaryImage
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Fiddler helped investigating what is being sent. By default, data passed in is being serialized. To prevent that, we need toe explicitly tell to not serialize it. "processData": false did the trick. Here is the working code:

```js
    function uploadingImage(binaryImage) {
        
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "...",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
                "Authorization": "Bearer ...",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
            },
            "processData":false,
            "data": binaryImage
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```